# How can I fixed npmw install command while generating project with JHipster?

Tags: java, node.js, jhipster

I used JHipster. Program throw error when generating code. In the beginning Jhipster didn't see JAVA_HOME, I've fixed that. After that **npmw install** didn't work. I thought JHipster couldn't find **node.exe** thats why i've checked that with node -v shown v16.17.0. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2L6o.jpg)

I changed NodeJs version, but didn't worked.
I followed to many guides but any one hasn't work.

Comment: Which version if JHipster? Have you tried removing .npmrc file?

Comment: Version was 7.9.3. I didn't remove file. I've found solution(maybe). I remove node js and JHipster after that i install again. Installed Node JS 14, npm, nvm and JHipster after that I use Vue and it's worked. I've question. Can Jhipster work with Angular?

Comment: JHipster can generate frontend code in Angular and is compatible with Angular CLI. Please read the doc https://www.jhipster.tech/using-angular/